# Are there any scenarios in which multiple inheritance is necessary?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Are there any scenarios in which multiple inheritence is necessary? Please provide examples.

Comment: Yes. Do you want examples, too? You should ask for some.

Comment: No. Most Turing complete languages don't support it.

Comment: I think this one is close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573913/a-use-for-multiple-inheritance

Comment: Are you asking about C++ or programming in general?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Arguably nothing in CS is necessary beyond increment- and move-register operations. I don't think OP means that. I think he's talking about situation in which multiple inheritence is the best solution to solve a given problem rather than the only possible solution.

Comment: @Neil - I think the key word is "necessary".  Most components of a modern language are not necessary, but rather useful.  In C++, MI is rather useful to provide capabilities similar to what Interfaces provide in Java and C#.

Comment: @Welbog I assumed he was asking if it was necessary (which it appears he was) and it isn't. Personally, I hardly ever use it in my own C++ codfe, and wouldn't really mind if it was removed from the language. I don't think it's a bad feature, however.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: If that's what he's asking then this is an incredibly dumb question. Even if that is what the OP intended, I will still interpret it my way because it's more interesting that way.

Comment: @Welbog You interpret how you like, and I'll do the same. I don't think my interpretation yeilds that dumb a question, however.

Comment: You can always work around it and use single inheritance, so you could argue that is nevery nessary. But somtimes it makes the design and coding more elagant (most of the time it is abused), and for those times I thank the C++ gods for leaving me with the tools I want rather than the rubber encased sticks provided by other language gods.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: If I were to ask you "are classes necessary" would you think it's a dumb question?

Comment: My Analogy: A moterbike is more dangerous than a car. And I can do everything that a moterbike does by using a car and a bit of walking. BUT I don't want my moterbike taken away just because some users are not as experienced as I am. Let the foolish die and the experienced utilise their tools appropriately.

Comment: @Welbog I wouldn't think it dumb. You can certainly write some very useful C++ code without using them. Actually, it's kind of an interesting question, if you remember that C++ is a multi-paradigm language.

Comment: @all Please let me restate - I don't think MI is a bad feature of C++.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simulate something like Interfaces that other OOP languages have, then you'll need to use multiple inheritence.

Comment: +1, exactly what I was coming to say

Comment: Except that interfaces are a restricted special case of the more generic multiple inheritance (e.g. a pure virtual abstract base class).

Comment: More to the point, an interface is a *contract* of implementation; a class-inhheritance is *actual* implementation. You can have both contract *and* implementation (pure virtuals + implemented functions), unless you language limits you to one-and-only-one implementation inheritance (aka Java, C#, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Anything which "requires" inheritance, and which you want to use more than once on a single class, or combine in a single class, "requires" multiple inheritance.

Common C++ idioms which use inheritance include:

- Java-style interfaces using abstract classes containing only pure virtual functions
- Mixins, including simulated dynamic binding via CRTP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), or `boost::noncopyable`.
- Policy-based design (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)
- Provision of type traits

So, if you want a single class implementing multiple interfaces then you need multiple inheritance. If you want a policy-based iterator type, then you need multiple inheritance (once for the policy, and once for the traits).

I put "requires" in snigger quotes because obviously in all cases you can write a program having the same output, and which does not use multiple inheritance (the "Turing complete is all we care about" argument). However, Turing completeness is *not* all we care about, and we usually have goals in writing software beyond Turing's concept of a program with input and output. We care what the source looks like. Hence, "necessary".

Answer (score 1):

With pure abstract classes you can have interfaces, like you do in Java or C#

Answer (score 0):

When the developer is lazy and doesn't want to produce a better class design that wouldn't need multiple inheritance ;-) I primarily code in C# and have never found a scenario that caused me to curse their design of only allowing single inheritance.

That being said, being able to implement multiple interfaces **is** really handy.

Comment: But you have most likely used multiple interfaces (Or used both inheritance and interfaces). But that would be multiple inheritance in c++, because c++ don't have interfaces as a independent concept. (A c++ developer just think about a interface as a class with no implemented methods).

Answer (score 0):

There are no scenarios where anything more than a Turing machine is *necessary*.

Answer (score 0):

When building COM objects.