# What the use of inheriting from multiple classes?

Tags: c#, oop

I saw some comments on forums, and it seems that people want to be able to inherit from multiple classes in c#. Why would you ever need this? I can't think of any use for this, but since there's people that want it, there's got to be some.

Comment: Most of the times if you need multiple inheritance, then your design is maybe somewhat incorrect:)

Comment: In the C++ days, you sometimes needed it, because of the lack of interfaces

Comment: See [A use for multiple inheritance ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573913/a-use-for-multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's an ASP.NET WebForms example:

I have one base class, a web control, let's say it is a simple `TextBox`.

I then inherit from the `TextBox` to provide formatting - `RichTextBox`.

I then want to have a `TextBox` that can spell-check - `SpellCheckingTextBox`.

What if I need a `SpellCheckingRichTextBox`? I would have to implement the spell checking or rich text logic again and inherit from one or the other.

In reality you would define them as interfaces: `ISpellCheckingTextBox` and `IRichTextBox` and implement them in a `SpellCheckingRichTextBox`. You could also write extension methods for `TextBox` to accomplish the same thing.

Multiple inheritance is fundamentally flawed because it views inherited classes as equal. What if both base classes had an `ID` field?

Answer (score 1):

People probably want to do this because they are accustomed to doing it in C++. It isn't allowed in C#. Which, IMO, is a good thing, from an application maintainability point of view. Often times, using multiple interfaces will accomplish the same thing.n

If you have a base class with abstract methods properly designed and it's know that the inheriting object will only need the methods defined in that class, you have have a valid design pattern that doesn't require MI.

Comment: Very few people actually use MI in C++.  Really, people want to use MI because they don't know how to do it the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance was sometimes used in C++ (and other languages) to allow a class to inherit properties and code from multiple base classes. When you have interfaces, like in C# and Java, there really is no need for multiple inheritance, so it was not implemented in those languages.

Here's a good article on multiple inheritance in Eiffel:

http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/bmarticles/joop/multiple.html

Comment: "No need" is overstrong: yes, interfaces do most of what MI provides, but mixins provide a powerful idioms for combining orthogonal behavioural policies. Whether that power is worth the troubles of the "diamond of death" is another issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

One legitimate case for wanting it in C# is to make a derived object MarshalByRef.  For example, say I want to do the following:

```
public class FooCorpClass
{
  // This class is defined in a 3rd party library and thus can't be changed
}

public class MyFoo : FooCorpClass, MarshalByRef
{
  // I can't do this because MarshalByRef isnt' an interface
}
```

Personally I see it as a shame that you can't have multiple inheritance if there aren't collisions, or have a collision handling mechanisms, but them's the breaks.