# Question about a possible design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have such a design in my mind.... My aim is to reuse the program with some features included and without some features.
What is it called in the literature?
More information: there are events.. Events cause calls to function1() or function2()...

Features have functions which are called when events takes place.
A feature may influence what functions are called at a event.
A feature may influence what is executed for more than one event.

So it looks it could be the observer pattern  + hasa relationship...

```
class feature1
{
void feature1functionx();
void feature1functiony();
}

class feature2
{
void feature2functionw();
void feature2functionz();

}

class program: feature1, feature2
{
 vector<string> data;
void function1()
{
 feature2functionw();
}
void function2()
{
 feature1functiony();
 feature2functionz();
}
void execute()
{
  function1();
  function2();
}

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Inheritance models a `IS-A` relationship.

It would seem natural here to use a `HAS-A` relationship if you wish to reuse the functions: and that is composition.

```
class program
{
public:
  void function1()
  {
    m2.feature2functionw();
  }
  void function2()
  {
    m1.feature1functiony();
    m2.feature2functionz();
  }
  void execute()
  {
    this->function1();
    this->function2();
  }
private:
  feature1 m1;
  feature2 m2;
};
```

I know that private inheritance is sometimes thought of as a short-cut, but it does not bring anything to the table here, so prefer composition as it does not tie you as much.

**EDIT**: Added the definition of the methods since it apparently wasn't that clear.

Comment: features may use the same underlying data structure... In that case, this does not seem to be good...

Comment: @Aftershock: I fail to see why this would be a problem.

Comment: @Aftershock: It's kinda difficult to answer that without having a perfect understand of what exactly are your "features" and what they share.

Comment: @Matthieu M. HAS-A == aggregation?

Comment: @Kezzer: HAS-A = containment. @Aftershock: it is up to the `program` class to define its interface and call `m1` and `m2` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This idea seems strange and complicated to me. This is what refinement and replacement are for in a class hierarchy.

Specifically I would be looking for something like this:

```
class feature1
{
  virtual void function1();
  virtual void function2();
  void execute() {
    function1();
    function2();
  }

}

class feature2:public feature1 //this is your program class
{
  virtual void function1() 
  {
     feature1::function1() //call previous functionality to refine
     //do feature2 stuff here
  }

  virtual void function2()
  {
     //don't call base class to replace
     //do feature2 stuff here
  }
}
```

Now feature2.Execute() does what you want.

Comment: Sorry number of functions could be misleading...
These functions (function1,function2 in different classes) may not be related at all..

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted reminds me of the so-called "Template method" pattern. In theory, this pattern looks like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void execute()
    {
        function1();
        function2();
    }
private:
    virtual void function1();
    virtual void function2();
};
```

and then later in some class:

```
class Derived1 : public Base
{
    void function1()
    {
        //implementation here...
    }
};
```

and you then call

```
b->execute(); //b is of type Base* and points to an object of type Derived1
```

and get your stuff done.

Not sure how this would work in your case, probably not at all, but at least this is an example of a pattern very similar to what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like an interface class but it sounds like you are implementing a lot of code in those base classes rather than have them purely abstract, which is the common way of making interfaces in C++. I suppose this could work if you're sure the base classes will never share any names etc. I don't know if they could also be described as mixin classes as described in this question: [A use for multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573913/a-use-for-multiple-inheritance)